# What is alternative for window,addEventListener using nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm working with Angular/Nativescript app, and I need to do something when user taps on his mobile screen, and don't know how to do it properly. For example, for my angular web app version I have something like this:

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => save());
  window.addEventListener('keydown', () => save());
});
```

For my mobile version I need to do something like this, but with every tap or touch events on my mobile. I know that I can't use window like above.  How can I do this?

Comment: You will have to add touch listener to your root layout.

Comment: I did it with (tap)="registerUserActivity($event)" and it's working but (touch) event is not fired. I can't register user activity only for tap event

Comment: ok, my bad. It's working thx :)